# Can I get a callable reference to an operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to get a callable reference to an operator (such as `===`) in TypeScript?

The motivation is this function:

```
function dedup<T>(values: T[], equals: (a: T, b: T) => boolean): T[] {
  return values.reduce<T[]>((prev, cur) => {
    if (prev.filter((value) => equals(value, cur)).length == 0) prev.push(cur);
    return prev;
  }, []);
}
```

This returns an array with duplicates removed, with equality of items defined by the `equals` function passed in. But if I just want to use `===` as `equals`, then I have to construct a completely superfluous anonymous function:

```
dedup([1, 2, 3, 2], (a, b) => a === b)
```

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
dedup([1, 2, 3, 2], ===)
```

or words to that general effect, but I can't figure out how to get a callable reference to an operator such as `===`.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: *"I'd like to be able to call it like this:"* i mean... sure... give the function in the prior snippet a name and put it somewhere accessible.

Comment: It's not _"completely superfluous"_; your code doesn't work without it. You can't just pass an operator, syntactically that makes no sense (in JS _or_ TS).

Comment: "callable reference to an operator" That's what a function is.

Comment: It's worth noting that in some Lisp dialects the various operators are in fact function names. However, JavaScript is not a Lisp dialect.

Comment: You cannot do that, but you can make the `equals` argument optional and simply fall back to `===` if nothing is provided.

Comment: As for the example function, it should be `[...new Set([1, 2, 3, 2])]`. That `dedup` is O(n^2) time, bad idea for a generic function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and others - I don't see how this is a stupid question.  There are many, many other languages where either operators are callable functions or they are aliases for callable functions (C++, Python, some Lisps, Lua etc etc) and the question is whether javascript and typescript have something similar.  Adding an extra layer of function call to every comparison should be avoided, if possible (but it isn't, it seems).

Comment: @Ry - Yes, I'd do that, except that `new Set(x)` will _only_ use `===` to compare elements of `x`; it is missing the key feature of `dedup`.  For the trivial case presented in the question it works, but for most cases I'm interested in it doesn't.

Comment: I guess I could replicate the functionality of `Set` using object indexing (or a `Map`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot reference an operator in javascript.

But you can create a function to use instead of an operator that applies your operator how you need.

For example:

```
const isIdentical = (a: unknown, b: unknown) => a === b
```

Then you can pass in that function:

```
dedup([1, 2, 3, 2], isIdentical)
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbJABwDwBUB8AFAG4CGANiKgM4BciuA2gLoA0iqAjiBXYoaXq52AIyEBKRAF58iEXDjlUpMOKEtEAbwBQiRACdUUEPqRlKNAHSGMEVHhZFCmQ8XYQTkmVt17EMYH4XVGJLYBhyKFR9QhIKKi9ZLh5yajiLd09xSyUwAHMoAAtpKUQABklg0MwQakLCD31xAG5fPUNjU0Qq1r0AX3YWFu0+7W0IBGoof2oASTQwWAgKaX5BRHAAazA4AHcwUXotnf3ExFIS0pExtAxMQkYARnYAJnYAZle2GfnURZhluRxNogA)